# iOS- UIAlert is only showing "OK" after changing the app icon to an alternate one

Tags: ios, swift, appicon

I have a place where I am changing the app icon for my app. I can get it so that the app icon actually changes, however, the alert that is supposed to pop only shows "OK". There is no text or picture to indicate that the icon changed.

[just okay alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdAMr.png)

I'm wondering if maybe there is a problem with the view hierarchy? I've tried placing the change function in multiple places in my app, and each time it does change the icon, but the alert is still wrong. Also, I can't find any errors getting printed to the console.

Here is my code for calling the icon change:

```
UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(ThemeCenter.shared.alternateIconName, completionHandler: nil)
```

I expect the alert to tell the user that the app icon has been changed and show the image that the icon was changed to, like so: 
[correct alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wryDs.png)
As far as I know, this should happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being that somewhere in our code, we were extending `UIAlertController` and overriding the `viewDidLoad` to set a tint color. For some reason, this override was making the top of the alert not show up. Taking out the `viewDidLoad` override solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an alert and add an image view to it :

```
let showAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Demo Alert", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 250, height: 230))
imageView.image = image // Your image here...
showAlert.view.addSubview(imageView)
let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: showAlert.view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 320)
let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: showAlert.view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 250)
showAlert.view.addConstraint(height)
showAlert.view.addConstraint(width)
showAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
    // your actions here...    
}))
self.present(showAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and you can change the size base on your need .

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't stop the "OK" button from displaying, since it is built in to the `setAlternateIcon` function. However, popping up my own UIAlert function does work just fine.